# Compare records in Excel spreadsheet to what is in DB

Tags: vba, excel

I originally thought that i was having a problem with the record set howeverm, it looks like now having done some tinkering that when i pass a value of null into my SQL Query String and attaempt to excute it does not recognise the string NULL to be NULL in SQL

Eg 
rst.OPEN "SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE Y = int AND Z = NULL"

Does not work however

rst.OPEN "SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE Y = int AND Z = datetime"

Is working fine??

```
        Sub CompareExcel()

        ' Macro1 Macro
        ' Macro recorded Aking


        Dim TargetDB As String
        Dim TargetDBUser As String
        Dim TargetDBPassword As String

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Select

        TargetDB = Cells(2, 14)
        TargetDBUser = Cells(3, 14)
        TargetDBPassword = Cells(4, 14)

        Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
        Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
        cnn.Open TargetDB, TargetDBUser, TargetDBPassword

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A7:A20000").Delete

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Select
            RowCounter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:A20"))

            CountAllExcellRecords = 0
            CountSuccessRecords = 0
            RowInSourceSheet = 1

                Do While RowInSourceSheet <= RowCounter

                    SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("B1").Offset(RowInSourceSheet, 0)
                    Worksheets(SourceSheet).Activate
                    RowCountSourceSheet = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
                    CriteriaBuilder = "('"
                    ColumnCountSourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count
                    SourceSheetRow = 1

                        Do While SourceSheetRow < RowCountSourceSheet

                            QvAriable = " WHERE"
                            QtAble = ""
                            SourceSheetColumn = 0

                                Do While SourceSheetColumn < ColumnCountSourceSheet


                                    qvAriablen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)
                                    qvAriablem = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(SourceSheetRow, SourceSheetColumn)

                                    Worksheets(SourceSheet).Activate
                                    Cells.Range("A1").Offset(SourceSheetRow, SourceSheetColumn).Activate

                                        Application.Volatile


                                            Select Case True
                                            Case IsEmpty(ActiveCell): CellType = "Blank"

                                                If qvAriablem = "" Then toSQL = " Null "
                                                qvAriablem = toSQL

                                                QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = " & qvAriablem & ""
                                                QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)

                                            Case Application.IsText(ActiveCell): DataType = "Text"

                                                QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = '" & qvAriablem & "'"
                                                QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)

                                            Case Application.IsLogical(ActiveCell): CellType = "Logical"

                                                QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = " & qvAriablem & " "
                                                QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)

                                            Case Application.IsErr(ActiveCell): CellType = "Error"

                                                QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = " & qvAriablem & " "
                                                QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)

                                            Case IsDate(ActiveCell): DataType = "Date"

                                                qvAriablem = Format(qvAriablem, "MM/DD/YYYY")
                                                QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = '" & Format(qvAriablem, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "'"
                                                QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)


                                            Case InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, ":") <> 0: CellType = "Time"

                                                qvAriablem = Format(qvAriablem, "MM/DD/YYYY")
                                                QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = '" & Format(qvAriablem, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "'"
                                                QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)


                                            Case IsNumeric(ActiveCell): CellType = "Value"

                                                Worksheets("INPUT").Activate
                                                RowCountExceptions = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("I:I"))
                                                Exceptions = 2
                                                eXceptionCount = 0

                                                    Do While Exceptions <= RowCountExceptions

                                                        If qvAriablen = Cells(Exceptions, 9) Then

                                                        eXceptionCount = eXceptionCount + 1
                                                        QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = '" & qvAriablem & "'"
                                                        QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)

                                                        End If

                                                        Exceptions = Exceptions + 1
                                                     Loop

                                                        If eXceptionCount = 0 Then

                                                        QvAriable = QvAriable & " " & qvAriablen & " = " & qvAriablem & " "
                                                        QtAble = QtAble & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range("A1").Offset(0, SourceSheetColumn)


                                                        End If


                                                End Select


                                            If SourceSheetColumn < ColumnCountSourceSheet - 1 Then
                                            QvAriable = QvAriable & " AND "
                                            QtAble = QtAble & ", "
                                            End If

                                        SourceSheetColumn = SourceSheetColumn + 1

                                    Loop

                                rst.Open "SELECT * FROM " & SourceSheet & QvAriable, cnn
                                'rst.Open "SELECT * FROM UNIT_FUND WHERE CURRENCY_CODE = 'GBP' AND  UNIT_FUND_CODE = '150' AND FUND_NAME = 'MetLife Fidelity Cash Fund' AND  EFFECTIVE_DATE = '10/21/2009' AND CEASE_DATE =" & "NULL"
                                Sheets("Summary").Range("G2").CopyFromRecordset rst


                                CountAllExcellRecords = CountAllExcellRecords + 1

                                    If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then

                                        CountSuccessRecords = CountSuccessRecords + 1

                                    Else

                                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Select
                                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Select
                                        a = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceSheet & QvAriable
                                        NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
                                        Cells(NextRow, 1) = a

                                    End If

                                rst.Close

                             SourceSheetRow = SourceSheetRow + 1

                        Loop

                    RowInSourceSheet = RowInSourceSheet + 1

                Loop

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Select

            Cells(3, 3) = CountAllExcellRecords
            Cells(4, 3) = CountSuccessRecords
            Cells(5, 3) = CountSuccessRecords - CountAllExcellRecords


        End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is a bit tricky to read with those variable names and no obvious declaration types. Could you give us some examples of your table names as this looks really fiddly in your code and, of course, we can't see the contents of the worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

The `RecordCount` property depends on the cursor location and type. It appears that all you are doing is checking to see if you got any records, so you can just use:

```
If Not rst.EOF Then
```

instead of:

```
If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
```

Comment: Hi Guys the problem is that I am passing in Values of Null which is not returning a record set, but when i copy and paste the query over to SQL it runs fine for me. I have null as a string maybe that is the problem??

Comment: Yes, that won't work. You can't use `=` and you need to use `WHERE FieldName Is Null` as the criterion.

Comment: Thanks Rory Working perfectly now